# Unable to fetch model objects list returned by action using ajax call in mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller Action:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult CriteriasForAward(int awardId)
        {
            var criteriaList = _awardService.GetCriteriasForAward(awardId);
            return Json(new { data = criteriaList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Ajax Call:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Award").change(function () {
              var selectdAward = $("#Award").val();
            alert("Id" + selectdAward);
            var ServiceUrl = "/Nomination/CriteriasForAward?awardId=" + selectdAward;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: ServiceUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText)
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    debugger;

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    alert(key);
                });


                }
            });
        });
    });



</script>
```

All the things are going good..Also ajax call is succeeded,the data field contain array of all objects returned by ajax but when i wanted to alert key of each item for testing then it alerts undefined for only once..
If i debug it in browser then it contains values as shown in snapshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1YAP.jpg)

Comment: You returning an object containing and array so it would need to be `$.each(data.data, function (key, val) {` but you would be better off just changing the controller method to `return Json(criteriaList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Yeah Its working fine now..Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: ServiceUrl,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     error: function (xhr, err) {
         alert(xhr.responseText)
     },
     success: function (data)
     {
         debugger;
         $.each(data.data, function (key, val) {
             alert(key);
         });
     }
 });
```

by `Json(new { data = criteriaList });` you creating new Json object that have `data` property. So if you want to access to that, just add `.data`: `data.data`, or change the json property name, to make more readable.

Comment: yes data will be returned in data item so you have to use data.data

Answer (score 0):

In your response data is object so you have to call just like that

```
$.each(data.data, function (key, val) {
   alert(key);
});
```

There is another way to achieve this you have to send json_encode from controller.